# How to create a new column reading part of string in another column and transforming it to integer

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new column in a dataframe based on information on another column which is of string type.

```
dataframe name= total_data

class,name

 a, C-FRA_FRA-S18_FU_L_FUS_FR073_STR001-STR00

 b, C-FRA_FRA-S18_FU_L_FUS_FR074_STR010-STR011
```

I have tried using the find() method and it does not work, I obtain nan values for the new column total_data.Frame

```
total_data["Frame"]=total_data.name.str[total_data.name.str.find("FR0"):total_data.name.str.find("_STR")]
```

Using code above I obtain a new column that contains only `nan` values

I want to have a new column in the dataframe as follows:

```
class,name, Frame

a,C-FRA_FRA-S18_FU_L_FUS_FR073_STR001-STR001,73

b,C-FRA_FRA-S18_FU_L_FUS_FR074_STR010-STR011,74
```

and if possible that this new column contains integers.

Answer (score 1):

If all the strings are in the same format, you can use a regex and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) like so:

```
df['Frame'] = df['name'].str.extract(r"FR0(\d+)_STR").astype(int)

#   class                                        name  Frame
# 0     a   C-FRA_FRA-S18_FU_L_FUS_FR073_STR001-STR00     73
# 1     b  C-FRA_FRA-S18_FU_L_FUS_FR074_STR010-STR011     74
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function and apply it to the DataFrame column using `apply`:

```
# Example set-up:
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"class":["a", "b"], 
                        "name":["C-FRA_FRA-S18_FU_L_FUS_FR073_STR001-STR00", 
                                "C-FRA_FRA-S18_FU_L_FUS_FR074_STR010-STR011"]})

# Solution:
def str_func(s):
    ix1 = s.find("FR0")+3
    ix2 = s.find("_STR")
    return s[ix1:ix2]

df["Frame"] = df["name"].apply(str_func).astype(int)
```